# How to partition the frame of a camera so that each part can be compared only with itself during the course of a video?

Tags: python, opencv

I am using OpenCV with Python and I have the following problem I need to solve:

I am recording a video using a USB camera where light spots will appear on different parts of the frame, become brighter and eventually disappear (something like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwcV9.png). Overall the spots should remain in the same location as time progresses. I need the program to partition the camera frame such that there is only one bright spot per segment (something like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/8z3tr.png). I then want to treat each camera segment as separate. This is so that I can then compare each bright spot only with itself over the duration of the video and see how it evolves.

Any advice on how to approach this or what methods to use is greatly appreciated.

I know how to detect each bright spot on a photo but I am not sure how to partition the camera frame such that there will be a bright spot eventually appearing in each segment.

EDIT: I realize that I didn't specify that every time there may be a different number of spots in total appearing on the video. Therefore, each time I will need different number of segments and different coordinates/dimension sizes for the segments.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, the problem is that there are 5 spots over time, so you need 5 segments? You've got 5 pairs of `Xi,Yi `coordinates? The trivial solution is to assign each point of the image `X,Y `to segment `i` based on a simple nearest-neighbor criterium. But I'm not sure about the underlying problem.

Comment: In this example there are 5 spots appearing at different points in time, yes. I need to partition the camera frame so that a segment will never contain more than one spot over the course of the whole video. I think the tricky part is that for each video frame I can find the spots but the spots need not all be present on the same frame (i.e. at the same time).

Comment: That obviously means you can't do the segmentation in real time. Other than that, I don't see a problem.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But how do I approach extracting how many bright spots will be appearing in total during the video (which will tell me how many segments I will need) and how to set my segment coordinates so that there is only one spot per segment? Each time there may be a different number of bright spots appearing, which means that I will need different number of segments and different sizes/locations of these segments.

Comment: That is just programming? Loop over all frames, count the number of unique bright spots across all frames? And since you segment by nearest neighbor, *by definition* each segment has one bright spot.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram

Comment: Thank you! That helps. I'll start there.

Comment: You can just take the maximum on the time scale. Then all the spots will be visible in the final image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my question. There are two cases:

Case 1: If the spots appear at the same locations (more or less) and there is a **fixed** number of them always, then all you need to do is use the cv2.findContours method and extract the bounding rectangles using cv2.boundingRect(contour). This works because OpenCV always starts searching for contours from the bottom right corner of the screen. As a result, the numbering of the contours in the hierarchy will be consistent and each bright spot will have the same number.

Case 2: If the spots remain more or less stationary but their number changes, then a more detailed approach is needed. Either manually ensure that you are not comparing different spots or attempt segmenting the frame using Voronoi diagrams as pointed out by @MSalters.